# The process killed while installing dgl

Tags: linux, dgl

I previously installed dgl2.1.0, but later found out that it doesn't support cuda, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled dgl2.1.0+cu181

Well I don't know what problem I encountered. After downloading the installation package, the process killed itself without any error messages. The following is the complete output

```
(graduation)root@xxx:~/venv/graduation# pip install  dgl -f https://data.dgl.ai/wheels/cu118/repo.html
Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple
Looking in links: https://data.dgl.ai/wheels/cu118/repo.html
Collecting dgl
  Downloading https://data.dgl.ai/wheels/cu118/dgl-2.1.0%2Bcu118-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (748.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 748.2 MB 589 kB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

I have repeated this problem many times and still encounter this problem. In addition, reopening a window is also useless.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it's a bit comical, there's not enough memory.

And I found that the dgl+cu version is nearly a hundred times larger than the version that does not support cuda :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).